# Why is kernel "rescheduling" causing so many wakes-from-idle?

Tags: kernel, power-management

PowerTOP reports that the majority of wakeups are being caused by `[Rescheduling interrupts]`, `[kernel scheduler]`, and `[kernel core]`.

What are these, and can I do anything to reduce the number of wakeups they are causing?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be normal... at least last time when I tried to hunt down this problem I read somewhere the exact explanation... And as far as I can remember it was not a problem.

Tough you can find a documentation here: [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReschedulingInterrupts)

Also you could run powertop as sudo and look for the C-States. If they are in idle at lowest it should be ok.